# What's wrong with mysqli::get_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$postId = $_GET['postId'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'database', 'name_db');
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE postId = ?
");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $postId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();//Call to undefined method 
$info = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($info);
```

And I get some error marked above. What have i done wrong?

EDIT:

changed fecth_array() to fetch_array()

Answer (score 15):

As others have stated, it is only available in bleeding edge PHP. You could do something like this ([answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016169/php-mysqli-return-row-and-set-to-var-help/7016350#7016350)):

```php
function bind_array($stmt, &$row) {
    $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $params = array();
    while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}

// ....
bind_array($stmt, $info);
$stmt->fetch();

echo json_encode($info);
```

Or use [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) if you have a simple query with no parameters - **don't use it with dynamically generated SQL-statements**.

Comment: Please don't recommend "downgrading" from prepared statements to bogstandard strings. It's hard enough getting people to go the other way.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: right - thanks for the reminder, I've added a disclaimer. Not sure if I should remove the reference completely.

Comment: It is weird that "downgrading" is the only real option PHP gave us on some situations.

Comment: I tried to use wile stms->fetch() but it's skipping the first record. How can we loop over all result records?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in php documentation [mysqli_stmt::get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php), this method is supported since PHP 5.3.0.

And it is stated in the *user notes* section that:

> This method requires the mysqlnd driver. Othervise you will get this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using old version of PHP not supporting get_result() as stated on manual page

```
(No version information available, might only be in SVN)
```

Comment: This is right. It usually means there's no release with this function in.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) doesn't give any clear information on which minimum version of PHP is needed for `get_result()` to work:

> (No version information available, might only be in SVN)

I don't know the background to this, but it may simply not be available in your PHP version.

You could use [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) instead.

Comment: Ok, I thinkt that might be the case. But can I ask how I can get rows in a result set using mysqli and prepared statements?

Comment: I don't like using fetch, because I have so much columns. Is there another way?

Comment: @Woho [`fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for example

Answer (score 0):

I´m guessing it´s the line below that, change:

```
$info = $result->fecth_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

to:

```
$info = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: ok changed that. But php issued an error before mysqli::fetch_array();

Answer (score 0):

check to see it your PHP mysql native driver is enable. get->result() only works when mysql native driver is enable. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php