# Can't use Get_result or fetch_assoc, mysqlnd not on shared servers

Tags: php, mysqlnd

Hostgator and Webhostingpad have both told me that mysqlnd is their default to which I have found the libmysqlclient is their default driver, So I am having a troubled time trying to get my prepared statements to function properly without using mysqlnd.

```
if ($stmt = $local->prepare("SELECT * FROM importdata WHERE AID=?")) 
{
$stmt->bind_param('i', $rID);
$stmt->execute();
$Recordset1 = $stmt->get_result();
$row_Recordset1 = $Recordset1->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();
}
```

I understand I have to use bind and fetch results? How do I create an array to be able to continue to display all my info on my site?

```
<?php echo $row_Recordset1['TestImage']; ?>
```

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752815/mysqli-get-result-alternative ... but I appreciate how you want an exact duplicate of the `get_result` function.