# Replacement for mysqlnd supported codes

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

So i have done my whole project using mysqli prepared statements.Now my hosting providers are saying that  "mysqlnd is not supported in our cloud servers".
My code looks like

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM hr_admin WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > "0")
{
$member = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I really need a alternative for this code.Please don't mark as duplicate because i search whole but could not find a proper replacement.I got replacements for `get_result()` &  `$result->fetch_assoc();` but not for `($result->num_rows > "0")` . I want to use `PDO` but as my whole project is in this. I badly need help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need alternatives for `$result->num_rows > "0"` because you don't need this condition at all:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$member = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($member)
{
```

Comment: `$result = $stmt->get_result();`  `$member = $result->fetch_assoc();` There are the ones not working

Comment: you said in your question that you "got replacements for get_result() &  $result->fetch_assoc();" Can you make your mind, please?

Comment: Yeah got it after posting the comment

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752815/mysqli-get-result-alternative) i was referring to this but it's not working ..

Comment: So you want a magic wand that will make your code work without any rewrite nor installing mysqlnd nor any other effort on your side? Good luck in search - that's all I can say.

Comment: You don't have to be rude.. I dont want any magic wand, i just want to sorted out my problem. U ve no idea the efforts m giving.