# NO mysql native driver causes an error

Tags: php, mysqli

i used to use functions like this one:

```
 function data_user($dbc,$email){

  $q = "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE email= ?";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $r = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  return $r
}
```

and then i call them inside my html code like this:

```
$r = data_user($dbc,$email);
while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r){
echo $info['user_name'];
}
```

it was working absolutely fine on my old server but then i moved my website to a new server which does not support mysqlnd so my website shows an error says that mysqli_stmt_get_result is undefined function,
I have contacted my host support service and the said there is no way to install mysqlnd on the server so i need to change my code, I have tried many other solutions but none of them actually works as i want,
any help is appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752815/mysqli-get-result-alternative

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Is there anyway you could change the PHP version you use?

Comment: @You Hidden in the question _I have contacted my host support service and the said there is no way to install mysqlnd on the server_

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That would be true, however `mysqlnd` is compiled by default in `PHP 5.4`, and most hosts *do* give the user the option to use different stable versions of `PHP`.

Comment: @You I repeat the OP already asked that question and was told **I have contacted my host support service and the said there is no way to install mysqlnd on the server** I think that means they WONT do it rather than they cannot do it

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I highly doubt the host won't allow OP to use a different PHP version, especially considering the last release of PHP 5.3 (the last php version that didn't include `mysqlnd` by default) was over 2 years ago.

Comment: @You are missing the point. OP say mysqlind is missing. The host says they will not install it. This is a waste of both of our times. If the OP asks his host and says he was told by his host that they **will not install mysqlind** then we have to assume that the host does not want to for some reason. Probably to encourage somone on a cheap cheap plan to upgrade to a more expensive one!

Comment: @WillParky93 works :), thank you very much

Comment: my php version is 5.6.2 but the guy in the chat said that my server is shared with other users and can not be updated for one user only @You