# Fetching in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to convert the following to predicted statements. Can you please tell me where Im going wrong.

```
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $userid . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user);
```

I have no luck trying to convert this. What I have so far:

```
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$userinfo->bind_param("i", $userid);
$userinfo->execute();
$row = $userinfo->fetch_assoc();
$userinfo->close();
```

Further on in code (As for why I need this):

```
<input class="form-control" name="charname" value="<?php echo $row["charname"]; ?>" required/>
```

### EDIT 1:

(I haven't tried localhost yet. But when I use the get_result() alternative it still doesnt work)

```
$userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$userinfo->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$userinfo->execute();
$result = $userinfo->get_result();
$userinfo->close();

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

When I change it back to this, it works.

```
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $userid . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user);
```

### EDIT 2:

Removed get_result(); in EDIT 1

$db is used to connect.

```
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

-

```
var_dump($userinfo->execute());
```

Returns:

```
bool(true)
```

-

```
var_dump($result);
```

Returns:

```
object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: You don't need to do real_escape_string when you use bind_param. What happens when you try?

Comment: @aynber Still doesnt work even without it

Comment: What about it isn't working? Do you get an error message? Try using `mysqli_error()` to see if it gives you any information.

Comment: @aynber no error message from mysqli_error()

Comment: https://twitter.com/ShrapnelCol/status/811554258927702016 Instead of guessing the proper syntax you have to learn it from the manual page. And then move to PDO

Comment: Did I mention PDO?

Comment: I see `mysqli_real_escape_string($con` then I see `mysqli_real_escape_string($db`, so which one of those is the right variable used to connect with? You're not checking for errors in any way, either via php or the query. Nor do we know if the session was started and if it holds value.

Comment: *"no error message from `mysqli_error()`"* - that's because and if you didn't include the argument for it `mysqli_error($con)`, nor are you using error reporting. You're just assuming your code works.

Comment: `return $RESULT;` but using `$result` in `$result = get_result($userinfo);` - If you're intending on using that variable, well those are 2 different animals altogether and is considered as being an undefined variable. And error reporting would have told you about it, but you didn't use that, as I told you twice already?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `mysqli_real_escape_string($db` I've just changed the name of the variable. `$db` is used. mysqli_error(); is later on in the code. Session has also started as it all does work if I don't use prepared statements

Comment: *"I haven't tried localhost yet" - what exactly do you mean by that? You're not running this as `file:///` directly into your browser, are you?

Comment: *"$db is used."* - and you're using `$con`?? I honestly don't know where to throw myself here anymore. Why even use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, you're using a prepared statement. Using those together will have adverse effects.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Im running the file on virtual hosting. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, I have changed that in prepared statement (dont use it anymore)

Comment: I'm curious; are you trying to find if a record/row exists?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I know it exists as the user is logged in, this is basicaly settings page that if the fields are filled in, shows them. `<input class="form-control" name="charname" value="<?php echo $row["charname"]; ?>" required/>`

Comment: *"this is basicaly settings page that if the fields are filled in, shows them"* - Your posted code doesn't support what you're really wanting to do. To check for required fields (if this is what you're really asking about), is to add `require` to inputs and also check if any of those are not empty in a conditional statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mean to show the value if it is already in the DataBase. Like save info and see it in the field where you entered it after page refresh.
`value="<?php echo $row["charname"]; ?>"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- 
It works the way it supposed to with:
`$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $userid . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user);`

I just want to try and change that to prepared statements.

Comment: Look at one of my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724 under the mysqli_ prepared statement `$query = "SELECT email FROM tblUser WHERE email=?";` example. Based yourself on that block of code and then assign a session array to the binded result variable `$email_check` as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this statement below,

```
$row = $userinfo->fetch_assoc();
```

`$userinfo` is a statement object, not a mysqli_result object. So you can't use it in your code like *that*. Use [`->get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) method to get the result set from the prepared statement and then fetch the row from the result set, like this:

```
$userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$userinfo->bind_param("i", $userid);
$userinfo->execute();
$result = $userinfo->get_result();
$userinfo->close();

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Later, you can use this `$row` variable in your *input* element,

```
<input class="form-control" name="charname" value="<?php echo $row["charname"]; ?>" required/>
```

---

**Sidenote(s):**

- If you're using prepared statement, then you don't have to escape anything using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function. You can directly use `$_SESSION['usr_id']` in your `->bind_param()` method, like this:

  ```
  $userinfo->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['usr_id']);
  ```
- `->get_result()` method is available only with MySQL Native driver(mysqlnd), so it won't work if you don't have *that* particular driver installed.

Comment: The virtual hosting that Im using probably doesn't have the MySQL Native driver as it doesnt seem to work. Is there any way to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: @MMQVBN First test it on your *localhost* and check whether all the functionalities are working correctly or not. Then you can be sure that your hosting server doesn't have *that* particular installed.

Comment: @MMQVBN If *mysqlnd* driver is not installed in your server, then this is the workaround, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551477/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551477/5517143)

Comment: I haven't tried local host yet but even with the workaround it doesnt seem to work. Is there anything else I could try? (Edited the question with what I have now.)

Comment: @MMQVBN `$result = get_result($userinfo);` is wrong, it should be `$result = $userinfo->get_result();`, **as given in the answer**.

Comment: I tried `$result = $userinfo->get_result();` first, but it didn't work so I tried the workaround(hopefully I did it correctly): `$result = get_result($userinfo);`

Comment: When I do '$result = get_result($userinfo);' the page dissapears after 'echo $row["charname"];'

Comment: @MMQVBN In *that* workaround, `get_result()` is a custom function to emulate  the functionality of MySQLi's `->get_result()` method. If you're using `$result = get_result($userinfo);` then have you defined that function as well?

Comment: @MMQVBN Use `var_dump()` to debug the issue further. Do `var_dump($result);` and see what you're getting. Also, check the status of `->execute();` statement using `var_dump($userinfo->execute());`.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul No idea if OP's paying attention to any of my comments up there. I must've left 3-4 comments but they probably feel being bombarded with so many that they don't know which way to throw themselves. Too bad you had to be chased down such a deep rabbit hole and for well over an hour.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, sometimes it happens. We really can't help them if they don't respond to our comments, or follow our debug steps. *sigh*

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Have a look at my comments to them up there, I think you'll agree on most or all of them. I think I'll have to literally spell it out to them as to how to use error reporting, *sigh*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I totally agree. Your comments raised pretty valid points here.

Comment: @MMQVBN 1. Switch to localhost and test your application with the given code snippet(s). 2. Turn on error reporting, add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not. 3. Make use of `mysqli_error()` properly, as pointed out by @Fred-ii also. 4. Go through @Fred-ii's comments and make sure you fix all of them.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I get nothing from `var_dump($result);` but from  `var_dump($userinfo->execute());` i get  `bool(true)`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul When I use `$result = $userinfo->get_result();` with `var_dump($result);` `object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul So Im geussing that `$result = $userinfo->get_result();` is working. But why is the page cut then

Comment: @MMQVBN First you said *I get nothing from var_dump($result);* and suddenly it started working. **Kindly read the answer and comments properly**. These kinds of trial and error won't get you too far. Since you know that `->get_result()` is working, now simply fetch the row from the result set, which also given in my answer.