# Results aren't being gathered from my database after trying to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, sql-injection

I am currently trying to prevent sql injection by using mysqli statements. However, after completing this transition, I am not getting results from my database anymore. I have a form where users can select economic data by narrowing down year intervals, months out of the year, and a location.Here is my current coding issues:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {


$gYear = $_POST["year"];
$gYear2 = $_POST["year2"];
$gMonth = $_POST["month"];
$gSelect = $_POST["location"];

if ($gYear > $gYear2) {

die('ERROR: Your second year cant be a time period before the first year you selected');
}

else {

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT $gSelect, Year FROM unemployed WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? and month= ?");
$query->bind_param('sss', $gyear, $gYear2, $gMonth);

$query->execute(); 

$result = = $conn->query($query)

echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Time</th><th>$gSelect</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){


echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row->Year;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $gMonth;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row->$gSelect;
echo "</td></tr>";

}




echo "</table";

}

} // end of main if statement

?>
```

It worked before I tried updating my query to prevent injection. I am currently using php 5.2.14 to work on this in case you guys were wondering. Am I missing a statement? Can anyone help me figure out what my issue is? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value for `$gSelect`?

Comment: $gselect is the locations that the user can choose from. I have a few listed in a drop down menu. They represent a few of my columns in my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->get_result()
```

seems to be unavailable in your version of PHP. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016169/php-mysqli-return-row-and-set-to-var-help/7016350#7016350) for a workaround.

Edit: Correction, thanks to comment

Comment: I have tried get_result(). I don't believe my version of PHP allows it.

Comment: $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2); What do the variables on the inside of the parenthesis represent?

Comment: The values to store the results of each fetch, I believe - see the examples in the docs for [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: They don't apply to the columns I am accessing in my database though.

Comment: Why not? 
`$query->bind_result($gcolumn, $year);
 while ($query->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $gcolumn, $year);
 }`

Comment: I just tried that. It still isn't printing anything. Nothing is showing up.